# Trying to setup an additional virtual terminal on debian jessie boot

Tags: debian, terminal, xorg

I have a bad keyboard on my laptop that I run Linux on.  Function keys F1 and F7 and the Backspace key do not send keystrokes to the system.  I have gotten used to pressing the left arrow, followed by DELETE in place of backspace, and I ignore F1 completely using the program menus to find options to make F1 unnecessary for me.

However, I'm having problems with F7. Alt-F7 should return me to the Xwindow environment after pressing Ctrl-Alt-F2 for a terminal window.  It really bothers me that older linux systems used /etc/inittab to tell the system how many virtual terminals to start up and put the Xwindow after the last virtual terminal.  With my jessie install I can't get the system to create a different number of virtual terminals.

I edited /etc/systemd/logind.conf uncommenting NAutoVTs=6 and ReserveVT=6, then changing the lines to read:
NAutoVTs=7
ReserveVT=7

should have fixed the problem by moving the Xwindow to Alt-F8.  After rebooting I discovered that this did not change anything. The Xwindow is still on VT7.

Next I tried editing /lib/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty-static.service. In the [Service] section I added getty@tty7.service to the end of the ExecStart= line.  When I rebooted the system I discovered that I now have a virtual terminal on tty8, but the Xwindow is still being loaded on tty7.  Is there any way I can get the Xwindow to move to tty8 without reinstalling the system and going back to the SysV init method?

I enjoy tampering with improvements on the system, but sometimes they puzzle me greatly and make me wish it was still the 1990's and X hadn't been invented yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Roger

Answer (score 1):

For GDM, you can set the first free terminal device in the /etc/gdm/custom.conf file.

```
$ cat /etc/gdm/custom.conf
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.
[daemon]
...
# Reserving more VTs for test consoles (default is 7)
FirstVT = 8
...
```

After that, at least restart gdm, b, to be sure, just `# reboot`.

Comment: Adding custom.conf to /etc/gdm3/ with the following statements, then rebooting: resulted in a text vt on F8 with X still on F7.   [daemon].  FirstVT = 8    unfortunately my phone keyboard won't let me put CR after lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about whether you can choose the tty device, but a reconfiguration of the Xorg server may be helpful:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

If it doesn't help, take a look at the Xorg configuration files, findable at:

```
$ find / -name xorg.conf -print 2>/dev/null
```

and check for helpful settings, or at least post some interesting sections, if any.

Comment: My system didn't seem to do anything with dpkg-reconfigure. Returned to the # with no messages. Find xorg.conf also doesn't display anything before returning to the # prompt.

Comment: What display manager (xdm, gdm, kdm, lightdm, …) do you use?

Comment: I'm using gdm3.

Comment: Okay, then try my new answer